# Use average of values in "where" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select the top x value from a query where the average of valid values for a particular field is above 10. Why is this throwing an error?

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM Table A
WHERE AVG(X1.parm) from (VALUES (A.F1),(A.F2),(A.F3)) as X1(parm) where X1.parm >0 and X1.parm is not NULL) > 10
```

Comment: 1) Aggregate function must be used in HAVING, not in WHERE. 2) You cannot compare aggregated and scalar values, calculate aggregated in a subquery then compare two scalar values.

Comment: Select **one** DBMS (MySQL and SQL Server are two different DBMSs) and remove wrong tag. Specify precise server version. Add table's DDL as `CREATE TABLE` script, some sample data as `INSERT INTO` script, show desired output **for this data** as formatted table.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? I haven't seen one like this being used in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is throwing an error because `avg()` is an aggregation function and cannot be in the `where` clause.

What you want seem to want is `apply`:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM Table A CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT AVG(X1.parm) as avg_parm
      FROM (VALUES (A.F1), (A.F2), (A.F3)) X1(parm) 
      WHERE X1.parm > 0
     ) a
WHERE avg_parm > 10;
```

The subquery calculates the average.  *That* calculation can be used in the `WHERE` clause.

Note that the comparison to `NULL` is unnecessary, because `>` filters out `NULL` values.

Also, this returns the average.  If you don't want the average in the results, just select `A.*` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, write the query that computes the averages in a CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). Then filter by average in the main query that uses the CTE.

```
WITH FooBar as (
  SELECT  A.*,
  AvgF = (select AVG(X1.parm) from (
    VALUES (A.F1),(A.F2),(A.F3)) as X1(parm)
    WHERE X1.parm > 0
    AND   X1.parm is not NULL
  )
  FROM    MyTable A
)
SELECT  *
FROM    FooBar
WHERE   AvgF > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM (
  SELECT F1, F2, F3, (F1+F2+F3)/3 AS Average
  FROM Table
) Subquery
WHERE Average > 10
ORDER BY Average DESC;
```

`AVG` works across records, not across columns, so you need to manually calculate it.

Remember to do an `ORDER BY` in descending order if you really want the ***top*** records.